# Python Continue statement if does not contain gaq tag

Tags: python

I am practising a little python and I was trying to extract content from a p tag. but when I grab the content, it prints out the gaq tags. 
I would like to print all p tags that do not contain the gaq tag, so i created the following script, with a continue loop.
if _gaq.push is in

don't print and continue with the loop.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://almondoilzone.com'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla')]

htmltext = browser.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

# HERE THE CONTINUE LOOP STILL PRINTS THE PARAGRAPH WITH _gaq.push

for post in soup.findAll('div',{"class","post"}):
    for paragraph in post.findAll('p'):
        if paragraph.find("_gaq.push")== -1:
            continue
        print paragraph.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `paragraph` is a BeautifulSoup element, `paragraph.find(...)` is BeautifulSoup's [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method, not Python's [`string.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find).

You probably want a loop like:

```
for post in soup.findAll('div',{"class","post"}):
    for paragraph in post.findAll('p'):
        if  "_gaq.push" in paragraph.text:    # <---------
            continue
        print paragraph.text
```